# Pi Zero 2: insufficient power from USB port

Tags: usb-power, pi-zero-w-2

i want to use my EzCap269 video grabber with my new Pi Zero 2. Unfortunately the video grabber won't work (power led is off) - so i assume it's getting not enough power (it's a USB3 device). I'm using my smartphone's standard power adapter for the Pi Zero2. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: If EzCap269 requires USB3 it won't work on a Pi Zero 2 as it is only USB2!

Comment: hmm .. it should be backward compatible .. i was thinking about using some power cable which will inject extra power - which is being used for external DVD-ROM-drives ..

Comment: Surely you would need to USB3 speed to capture video irrelevant of power issues.

Comment: it's for my ambilight and was already confirmed that it works - but the person used an ethernet-hub which supplied the extra power

Answer (score 1):

Ok - simple solution: using a OTG adapter for supplying extra power will do the trick